# Fast way to type check Symbol in a function with held arguments

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, typechecking

One can test if an argument is a Symbol without a explicit value using:

```
func[s_Symbol] = ...
```

If the function has a Hold attribute however, that pattern will match all Symbols, not only those without an explicit value.  I could use:

```
func[s_] /; Head[s] === Symbol = ...
```

but this comes with a greater performance penalty than I would like.  Adding a rule for `_Symbol` has a fairly small impact on performance, and `HoldFirst` does not appear to have any performance penalty, however `Head[s] === Symbol` has a significant overhead on a simple function.  Tests with `ValueQ` and `MatchQ[s, _Symbol]` are even slower.

*To clarify, I want to have two different definitions for* `func` *, with one for unassigned Symbols, and one for other arguments.*

**Is there a faster way?**

---

*Timings:*

```
f[x_] = 0;

f /@ Range@1*^6; // Timing

f[s_Symbol] = 1;

f /@ Range@1*^6; // Timing
```

```
   {0.391, Null}
```

```
   {0.531, Null}
```

```
Remove[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]

f[x_] = 0;

f /@ Range@1*^6; // Timing

f[s_] /; Head[s] === Symbol = 1;

f /@ Range@1*^6; // Timing
```

```
   {0.39, Null}
```

```
   {1.157, Null}
```

Comment: Interesting factoid. Didn't realize type checking came with such an overhead.

Comment: @Sjoerd I didn't mean this as a factoid, it's a real question.  Most functions are complex enough for the overhead to be comparatively small, but in simple cases it can be considerable.

Comment: @Sjoerd While we are at it, let me mention that there are cases when the proper use of the pattern-matcher for type-checking is crucial. Consider: `tst = Range[10^6];
MatchQ[tst, {__Integer}] // Timing ;                And @@ Map[Head[#] === Integer &, tst] // Timing`. This is cheating a bit since the dramatic difference is due to the packed nature of an array, but you can still get a factor of 10 or something even when array is not packed. This is important when you need, for example, to determine that the input to a function is a list of integers, for a large list.

Comment: @Sjoerd - I never heard of the word 'Factoid' but I like it because it sounds like 'Groupoid'. Anyway, I checked the meaning: " A factoid is a questionable or spurious—unverified, incorrect, or fabricated—statement presented as a fact, but with no veracity. " - Hmmm.

Comment: @ndroock1 interesting; "factoid" is similar to "verbage" in that I have heard both used incorrectly, in place of "fact" and "verbiage."

Comment: @nd I didn't to use it in that derogatory meaning. My intended meaning was "little fact" which is close to #2 in merriamw: 2 : a briefly stated and usually trivial fact

Comment: @Sjoerd that is the way I have used it myself, but now that I know it carries a negative connotation I will not use it that way any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pattern `s_Symbol` in the code with `HoldFirst` attribute will improve the performance:

```
In[121]:= Remove[f]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[s_Symbol] /; Head[s] === Symbol = 1;
f[_] = 0;

In[125]:= f /@ Range@1*^6; // Timing

Out[125]= {1.217, Null}

In[130]:= Remove[f2]
f2[s_Symbol] = 1;
f2[_] = 0;

In[133]:= f2 /@ Range@1*^6; // Timing

Out[133]= {1.123, Null}
```

Comment: I thought this would make things slower because it was in effect checked twice.  I should know by know it's always best with Mathematica to test and see. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The reason why usign `s_Symbol` improves performance is that it serves to reject explicit non-symbols quickly.

Answer (score 6):

You can get performance comparable to the fastest exhibited running times by delegating held symbol arguments to a non-held helper function `g`:

```
Remove[f, g]
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[_] = 0;
f[s_Symbol] := g[s]
g[_Symbol] = 1;
g[_] = 0;
```

Comment: Unlike Shasha's method, which I foolishly rejected before trying, I didn't even consider this.  Like many great ideas, it seems very simple after the fact.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it faster with this:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[x_] = 0;
f[s_Symbol] /; OwnValues[s] =!= {} = 1;
```

To compare, here is the one you used:

```
ClearAll[ff];
SetAttributes[ff, HoldFirst]
ff[x_] = 0;
ff[s_] /; Head[s] === Symbol = 1;
```

Now:

```
In[30]:= f /@ Range@1*^6; // Timing

Out[30]= {0.719, Null}

In[56]:= ff /@ Range@1*^6; // Timing

Out[56]= {1.25, Null}
```

This will be more effective when your arguments will mostly be non-symbols, and the reason that it is faster is that you can still use the `_Symbol` pattern to filter them out. For lists of symbols only, it may actually be slower:

```
symbTest = Table[ToExpression["sym" <> ToString[i]], {i, 100000}];
MapIndexed[If[OddQ[First@#2], #1 = First@#2] &, symbTest];

In[54]:= ReleaseHold[Map[f,Hold[symbTest]/.OwnValues[symbTest],{2}]]//Short//Timing
Out[54]= {0.234,{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,<<99964>>,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}}

In[58]:= ReleaseHold[Map[ff,Hold[symbTest]/.OwnValues[symbTest],{2}]]//Short//Timing
Out[58]= {0.141,{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,<<99964>>,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}}
```

Comment: Interesting use of `OwnValues` here, and a good analysis of list contents.  Any thoughts regarding `f[s_Symbol] /; Head[s] === Symbol` versus `f[s_Symbol] /; OwnValues[s] =!= {}`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard My testing show that the test `Head[s] === Symbol` is a wee faster on `x = Fold[{#1, {#2}} &, 0, Range[10000]];`. Then `Do[TestWithOwnValues[x], {10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming` gives 2.9 seconds, while `Do[TestWithHead[x], {10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming` completes in 2.4 seconds.

Comment: @Sasha, @Mr.Wizard  But @Sasha's observation is exactly what I also warned about in the answer - the point is not in the use of `OwnValues`, but in the ability to still filter out non-symbols or symbols with values fast. If anything, this tells us about the pattern-matcher internals: explicit patterns like `_Symbol` are obviously checked before the test in `Condition` is computed, which makes perfect sense to me.